# Payflow pro credit card error

Tags: magento-1.7, payflowpro

I am getting a problem when i try to checkout using payflow pro credit card method with magento,it show an error "Unable to read response, or response is empty". do anyone know why it occurs.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it is because of not using valid credit card details. use credit card details from your developer sendbox  account.

Comment: I it working for me.i was using these details
Visa: 422 2222 2222 22
Visa: 411 1111 1111 1111 1
It was throwing an error which seems as paypal communication error but it was card authentication error.Now i am using sendbox details of credit card and it is working.
Many Thanks